# Showing a set is dense in $l^1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I have been studying functional analysis and I came across this question: Show that $$F := \{(s_n)\in l^1 : (ns_n)\notin l^{\infty}\}$$ is dense in $l_1$.

So here is my approach and I would like some feedback if possible: $(e_n) \in l^1$ (a sequence with unit value in the nth position) is certainly part of this set as $(ne_n)$ is unbounded. We know already that the span of $(e_n)$ is dense in $l^1$. Every other sequence in F can be represented by the span of $(e_n)$. Hence, $(e_n)$ is dense in F itself. Hence, F is dense in $l^1$.

Is this correct? I am sorry that I can be very vague in structuring my arguments (I am new to mathematics) and was wondering if anyone could help me with structuring this better or correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: $(e_n)\notin\ell^1$, but $e_n\in\ell^1$; and $ne_n=(0,\ldots,0,n,0,\ldots)$ is still bounded.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This might be a stupid question, but what is the difference between $e_n$ and $(e_n)$? Do you have any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Comment: $e_n=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots)$ is a sequence; $(a_n)$ assumes $a_n$ are scalars, so it does not make sense to write $(e_n)$ in this context.

Comment: $(e_n)$ is a sequence whose individual terms are, themselves, elements of $l^1$: $$(e_n) = (e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,...)$$ $$= ((1,0,0,0,0,...),(0,1,0,0,0,...),(0,0,1,0,0,...),(0,0,0,1,0,...),..)$$ So $(e_n)$ is not an element of $l^1$ (as said already in the first comment of @Christomath).

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes sense now! Getting used to these notations now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $(s_n)\in\ell^1$.

Let $u_n:=\begin{cases}\frac{m}{2^m}&n=2^m\\0&o/w\end{cases}$; and let $\epsilon_n:=\frac{\epsilon u_n}{4}$.

Then $(\epsilon_n)\in\ell^1$ with $\|(\epsilon_n)\|_1=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, since $\sum_nu_n=\sum_m\frac{m}{2^m}=2$.
Consider $b_n:=s_n\pm\epsilon_n$, with the sign chosen to be the same as that of $s_n$;
then $(b_n)\in\ell^1$ since $\|(b_n)\|_1\le\|(s_n)\|_1+\|(\epsilon_n)\|_1<\infty$;
and $(nb_n)\notin\ell^\infty$ since $|nb_n|=|ns_n|+n\epsilon_n\ge n\epsilon_n$, and $nu_n=\begin{cases}m&n=2^m\\0&o/w\end{cases}$ is unbounded.

Hence $$\|(s_n)-(b_n)\|_1=\|(\epsilon_n)\|_1=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

This means that every ball around $(s_n)\in\ell^1$ has a sequence $(b_n)\in F$ within it.

Comment: Thanks! It's perfectly clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easiest to prove this directly. Fix some $\varepsilon>0$ and some $(x_n)\in\ell^1$. We know there must exist some $K\in\mathbb N$ such that $\sum_{n=K}^\infty|x_n|<\varepsilon/2$. Now note that there exists an infinite set $A\subset \mathbb N$ so that
$$\sum_{n\in A} 1/\sqrt n<\varepsilon/2.$$
Now define some $(s_n)$ by $s_n=x_n$ for all $n\leq K$. For all $n\geq K$ let
$$s_n=\begin{cases}1/\sqrt n &  \text{if}~ n\in A\\ 0 & \text{if}~n\notin A.\end{cases}$$
Clearly $(s_n)\in\ell^1\cap F$, and $\|(s_n)-(x_n)\|_1<\varepsilon$. As $(x_n)$ and $\varepsilon$ are arbitrary it follows that indeed $F$ is dense in $\ell^1$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Although as a beginner, little complicated to understand for me compared to the other answer.

Comment: @blueArrow No worries! I'm glad you found an answer that worked for you. The other answer and mine are basically equivalent. The set $A$ I mentioned is just the set of points where our chosen element of $F$ is non-zero. The other answer just explicitly characterised those points (which will be slightly different in his case) using powers of $2$, whereas I left it to you to think about why we can find such an $A$.

Comment: I see this now. Thanks for the explanation!